# Modify number keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need to create the iOS keyboard similar to attached image,  it is possible any how with the native solution? 
I have tried to assign a return key which is Done but i am getting following [image: this is the required image]

[image: This is what i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom input view with needed appearance.
To achieve this, you can use property [`inputView` if `UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619620-inputview):

> The custom input view to display when the text field becomes the first
>   responder.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) you can find a guide about custom input views.
Also I've created small example with custom input view without buttons: https://github.com/K-Be/KeyboardNotifications/tree/master_CustomInput .